# Script file for transferring a specific file to another folder

Tags: bash

I have a daily file to transfer between folders to update my WMS systems delivery schedules. The file is a .csv file and has a file named `MK_16-May-2013`. The file comes across with the date updated and is always one day ahead of todays date. I would then like to transfer this file to another directory.

So in essence

`MK_16-May-2013` from directory `\\dpg-lph-wms01\atms\live\Interface\UPS121\Backup`

to directory `\\354839-DPLV-RD1\Roadnet\Roadnet_Output_for_ATMS`

The directories should begin double back slash

Sounds easy to me but then I have no idea of how to write script files!

Thanks in advance of any help

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following bash script to transfer your files from one directory to another.  Let's say the first directory is `d1/` and the second directory is `d2/`, then you can do:

```
cp d1/. d2/ -R
```

Don't forget the dot (.) after the first directory as that's needed.